# Adding a library into a iOS project

Tags: ios, static-libraries

I installed [MumbleKit](https://github.com/mumble-voip/mumblekit) and I would like to use the library in a project. I tried following the instructions in the page, but just copying the MumbleKit icon in the new project does not make it appear in the target dependencies, while adding the whole project produces the familiar errors due to the obsolete syntax of the code used in the library. How do I add the library without having to compile everything together?

Thanks.

Comment: At the GitHub there is detailed tutorial how to add it

Comment: Yes, I saw it. But it was not clear enough for me to execute it with success. In particular it is not clear what they mean with: 
"to include MumbleKit with your application on iOS is to drag the MumbleKit.xcodeproj project inside your application's project, or workspace.", however I tried I had problems, either with compilation or with establishing the dependencies.

Comment: It means just drag&drop from Finder the file  `MumbleKit.xcodeproj` to your project. You will succeed only after performing all steps. Have you added all necessary frameworks, configured paths etc?

Comment: I did it (drag&drop from the Finder to the project file list pane). But then it does not show up in the target dependency options. The rest should be fine, but of course I could not test it until I have a way to call the methods of the library.

Comment: It should not appear in the target dependencies

Comment: So it is enough that the xcodeproj be in the file list and the compiled library in the libraries. But then how do I call the methods of the library, and what are they? Sorry for asking but I am quite unfamiliar with libraries.

Comment: You have header files in the search path, they will suggest autocomplete methods. Then linker will find actual implementations

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76288/discussion-between-azat-and-fabrizio-bartolomucci).

Comment: Ok, I put the scr directory in search paths. Posibly I need to include some .h files, yet I have really no cue about what methods to call to perform all the actions mumble is able to do. Autocomplete works if one already knows what to do!

Answer (score 0):

The procedure encompasses embedding the Mumblekit.xocodeproject into the main project by verifying the target and platform information are present and the subdirectory may be opened. Then the Mumblekit project must be inserted in the target dependencies. Then importantly it must be checked that all project have "build for active architecture only" set to NO. And upon compilation the generated library may be loaded in the project libraries. And finally it will be possible to include the library files as in:

```
#import <MKAudioInput.h>
```

and do operations with them. Thanks to Azat for having assisted me in this enquiry.

Comment: Setting build for active architecture only to NO is not very good because that points to the lack of architecture support. Apple reject binaries that do not include 64 bit slices. It would be better to investigate deeply to leave that setting in the YES state for DEBUG mode

Comment: I do not know what to do about it. By default it was set to NO for debug and yes for release. At any rate I think that setting it to NO implies the compilation for all architecture, thus also including 64 bits. Or am I wrong?

Comment: By default it set to YES for Debug and NO for Release. And it was so for me in my demo project. If you can't compile for 64 arch with that setting set to YES that mean the absence of 64 bit slice. If you set NO, 32 bit code will be executed in the compatibility mode

Comment: Yet, if I put it to YES, I do not compile at all! I wonder how could you, actually. At present I am stuck at another issue: programmatically creating mumble channels.
In fact I managed by experiments and by poking at the Mumble app code to have my app registered on the Murmor server, notwithstanding not yet able to receive calls.